# Android apk install on deviceanywhere

Tags: android, installation, device, apk

I downloaded my Android apk onto a Device on deviceanywhere. After the download, when I click on it, it asks "Do you want to install this application?". I click "Install", it comes back saying "Application not installed" with a warning symbol.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: there could be a number of reasons why. It could be signed incorrectly or not at all, it may not have fully downloaded so it is corrupt, there could be no space left on the device to install the app. If you can post the logcat when you get the error it would help give more information.

Comment: I have also had this problem twice, once was because my app used Google maps but I was using the debug api key, the second time was because I had set my phone to always install to the SD card.